# Running Apps Script Automation Code in a Google Form Response?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I would like to automate a Google Form response session using app scripts within the session. For example, if a form user selects answer B for Q1 from a multiple choice ABCD option, I want to automatically answer a later question, such as Q7, which assumes this answer.

Currently, I am only able to run apps scripts against a response after it has been submitted to the linked spreadsheet, using SpreadsheetApp. Is there any way to do this within the form response itself?

I have searched for answers for several hours and am starting to think this isn't possible, but find it hard to imagine.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no way that I know of except to roll your own html forms

Comment: Yes. Seems right. At least future colleagues will not waste time on it.